# What are these folders for? Can I remove them? How?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In a folder on the SVN server/repository that is designated for our project, there have appeared the following folders:

1. branches/
2. conf/
3. db/
4. hooks/
5. locks/
6. tags/
7. trunk/
8. README.txt (file)
9. format (file)

We have all the code in the trunk folder. There were, as far as I can remember, only 3 or 4 folders earlier.

Within the trunk folder, too, there are now these folders.

1. OurCode/
2. conf/
3. db/
4. hooks/
5. locks/
6. README.txt (file)
7. format (file)

I understand many of these folders or files are not necessary, but I can't be too sure.

My questions are:

1) What are each of these files and/or folders for?

2) Which are the ones that are not necessary?

3) How may I remove them from the server repository?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you mixed up a ***repository*** with a **working copy**. Did anybody accidentally checkout or export (*thanks, Rudi*) the repository into the folder where svn keeps it data?

(Note that this might be wrong depending on the backend your svn installation uses. I have only ever seen Berkley DB backends.)

Comment: This was also my first guess. Is there a .svn folder too?

Comment: @Rudi: Good catch. Maybe an export instead of a checkout?

Comment: Yep, although I wonder if the use of the term 'repository' is actually correct, and someone has just managed to check-in/import the Subversion metadata structures along with the code...? Also, this behaviour *might* be exhibited if Subversion is running in File mode instead of DB mode, in which case the Repository folder itself might look like this?

Comment: @Jonners: Yep, that's what my disclaimer is for. `:)`